# PyCharm terminal: weird background color for directories

Tags: terminal, pycharm

When using any dark scheme, the directories in the terminal have green background which is very unreadable.
With light scheme it is Ok. But you cannot change the scheme separately for editor area and terminal, although they are asking if you want this in the dialog window.

PyCharm community 2020.3, running on Ubuntu 20.10

[image]